# Conditionally subset or data set based on a row that starts from a specific character

Tags: r, dataset, subset

The short version of my big dataset looks like this:

```
> fMRIlog 

   Event       Code
   Picture     SRA2
   Picture     def
   Picture     R1incR2
   Picture     isi
   Picture     jit
   Picture     def
   Picture     FB_SRA2_64_eurocent
   Picture     MID1
   Picture     isi
   Picture     jit
   Picture     no$
   Picture     blueG
   Picture     FB_MID1_48_eurocent
   Picture     CSRA1
   Picture     isi
   Picture     jit
   Picture     cue1
   Picture     R2con
   Picture     FB_CSRA1_64_eurocent
```

The **SRA2**, **MID1**, and **CSRA1** are the names of my blocks in the experiment. I want to subset the whole data set for each block. Basically, what I need to do is to divide my big data set into small ones with `fMRIlog$Code ==` a string starting with the `FB_`

So, the data look like this in the end:

```
 > SRA

   Event       Code
   Picture     SRA2
   Picture     def
   Picture     R1incR2
   Picture     isi
   Picture     jit
   Picture     def
   Picture     FB_SRA2_64_eurocent

> MID

   Picture     MID1
   Picture     isi
   Picture     jit
   Picture     no$
   Picture     blueG
   Picture     FB_MID1_48_eurocent

 > CSRA

   Picture     CSRA1
   Picture     isi
   Picture     jit
   Picture     cue1
   Picture     R2con
   Picture     FB_CSRA1_64_eurocent
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar base R method:

```
myList <- split(df, cumsum(df$Code %in% c("SRA2", "MID1", "CSRA1")))
```

which returns

```
myList

$`1`
    Event                Code
1 Picture                SRA2
2 Picture                 def
3 Picture             R1incR2
4 Picture                 isi
5 Picture                 jit
6 Picture                 def
7 Picture FB_SRA2_64_eurocent

$`2`
     Event                Code
8  Picture                MID1
9  Picture                 isi
10 Picture                 jit
11 Picture                 no$
12 Picture               blueG
13 Picture FB_MID1_48_eurocent

$`3`
     Event                 Code
14 Picture                CSRA1
15 Picture                  isi
16 Picture                  jit
17 Picture                 cue1
18 Picture                R2con
19 Picture FB_CSRA1_64_eurocent
```

The `%in%` operator checks if the elements in the Code column are present in the `c("SRA2", "MID1", "CSRA1")` vector. These logical results are then cumulatively summed with `cumsum`, creating groups. These groups are used to split the result into a list of data.frames with `split`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, create a vector that can denote a different group id for each block using `cumsum` and then split on it:

```
split(fMRIlog, cumsum(dplyr::lag(startsWith(fMRIlog$Code, "FB_"), default = F)))

$`0`
    Event                Code
1 Picture                SRA2
2 Picture                 def
3 Picture             R1incR2
4 Picture                 isi
5 Picture                 jit
6 Picture                 def
7 Picture FB_SRA2_64_eurocent

$`1`
     Event                Code
8  Picture                MID1
9  Picture                 isi
10 Picture                 jit
11 Picture                 no$
12 Picture               blueG
13 Picture FB_MID1_48_eurocent

$`2`
     Event                 Code
14 Picture                CSRA1
15 Picture                  isi
16 Picture                  jit
17 Picture                 cue1
18 Picture                R2con
19 Picture FB_CSRA1_64_eurocent
```